# DHARMa outlier test is significant, what are my next steps?

Tags: r, outliers, nonlinear-regression, negative-binomial-distribution

I'm looking for information and guidance to help me understand the outlier test in DHARMa for negative binomial regression in R. Here is the diagnostic plot from DHARMa using the function simulateResiduals().

[image]

First off, The dispersion test is significant in the plot. Using testDispersion() on the model and on the residuals, I get the results of 2.495. Visually, the dots seem to align pretty well on the QQ line. The developer stated ' If you see a dispersion parameter of 1.01, I would not worry, even if the test is significant. A significant value of 5, however, is clearly a reason to move to a model that accounts for overdispersion.'[here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/490680/significant-dispersion-test) I conclude that the deviation is within the acceptable range for the NB regression.

Second, the Outlier test is also significant. I never had this before, and I can't find much information regarding how many outliers is okay vs not okay to have. Following the recommendation of DHARMa's developer, I looked at the magnitude of the outlier to investigate this. reference. Here is the code and output:

```
ModelNB <- glm.nb(BUD ~ Treatment*YEAR, data=Data_Bud) simulationOutput <- simulateResiduals(fittedModel = ModelNB, plot = T) testOutliers(simulationOutput, type = "binomial")

 DHARMa outlier test based on exact binomial test with
    approximate expectations

data:  simulationOutput
outliers at both margin(s) = 12, observations = 576, p-value =
0.00269
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.007968127
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.01081011 0.03610864
sample estimates:
frequency of outliers (expected: 0.00796812749003984 ) 
                                            0.02083333
```

Can someone help me understand this output? Is having 12 outliers per 576 observations okay? In statistics classes, I was told that taking out outliers was a big No-No. What does "true probability of success is not equal to 0.007968127" mean? Does it mean I can't accept H1 and need to accept H0 for the outlier???

Information on my model: `ModelNB <- glm.nb(BUD ~ Treatment*YEAR, data=Data_Bud)`

- BUD = The number of floral buds on a twig
- Treatment = 5 different fertilizer treatment
- YEAR = 2 different years (2020 and 2021)

I posted this in StackOverflow before being told it belongs here. [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74223643/dharma-outlier-test-is-significant-what-are-my-next-steps)

Comment: If it tells you which are outliers I would investigate to see if there is any reason why they are being identified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look too bad to me from the qqplot either. But you could also have a look on the histogram provided by

```
testDispersion(ModelNB, type = "DHARMa")
```

or calculate it using Pearson residuals

```
testDispersion(ModelNB, type = "PearsonChisq")
```

to get further impressions about the dispersion.

However, there may be a missing covariate, zero-inflation or zero-truncation that is causing this problem. Did you start with a Poisson model as suggested by Zuur and Ieno 2021? They suggest doing a Poisson model with model validation first, including `testZeroinflation()`, and then moving on to negative binomial, generalised Poisson, zero-inflated Poisson and so on, depending on what you find in the model validation. So you might end up with a different distribution that fits your data better.

The statement

> alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not 0.007968127

only tells you what the alternative hypothesis (H1) is, it doesn't tell you whether you should accept it or not. However, according to the p-value and confidence intervals, you should accept H1. So, according to this test, your 2.08% outliers are significantly higher than the expected 0.797% outliers calculated by simulating data based on your model. It is probably a good idea to investigate these outliers.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not sure if you considered also bootstrapping the outlier test as DHARMa gives a warning to do so with binomial regressions. I had the same warning which disappeared once I bootstrapped...